# Does Manusmriti contain any statements regarding manual labor?

Tags: manu-smriti

Is there any mention regarding manual labor in Manu Smriti?

Comment: Manual labor? In what sense?

Comment: @Wikash_ Yeah, in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

See [verse 7.138](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200804.html) on how a king can collect taxes from people who support themselves by personal labor.

> Mechanics (kārukā) and Artisans (śilpi), as also shudras who subsist by bodily labour,—the King shall make each of these work for one day every month.—(138)
>
> ---
>
> Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):
>
> Those who live by any kind of art he shall make work for him one day each month;—as also those who 'subsist by bodily labour'—i.e., **those śūdras who carry loads** &c.—(138)